# AWS CloudFormation : Invalid template property or properties [Type, Properties]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to Create a new Sql server - RDS instance (with more storage ) from an existing snapshot ID. Below is my CloudFormation template that's throwing the error:

> "Template contains errors.: Invalid template property or properties [Type, Properties]"

```json
"MyDB" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
    "Properties" : {
      "DBName" : { "Ref" : "NSGlobal" },
      "DBSnapshotIdentifier":"rds:xxxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-17-00",
      "AllocatedStorage" : "400",
      "DBInstanceClass" : "db.m2.xlarge",
      "EngineVersion" : "11.0"
    }
}
```

I copied this template from the AWS site http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-masterusername and tailored it. what's the problem ?

Comment: Remove "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09" and then check it will work the template version is not a AWS Resource property thats why the error

Comment: That's giving Template contains errors.: Template format error: unsupported type or structure. (line 1, column 1)

Comment: Can you paste your edited template?

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: Is this RDS a Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Resources" : {
        "DBInstance" : {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties": {
                "DBInstanceClass" : "db.m2.xlarge", 
                "AllocatedStorage" : "400", 
                "MasterUsername" : "myusername", 
                "MasterUserPassword" : "mypassword", 
                "DBSnapshotIdentifier":"xxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-17-00" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MasterUserName and MasterUserPassword are not mandatory, the template will be valid even without them.

Refer this thread for more information : [Creating SQL RDS instance in CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435803/creating-sql-rds-instance-in-cloudformation)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Engine property use the template below. This are the valid options for engine.

Valid Values: MySQL | mariadb | oracle-se1 | oracle-se | oracle-ee | sqlserver-ee | sqlserver-se | sqlserver-ex | sqlserver-web | postgres | aurora

```
        "MyDB" : {
          "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09", 
          "Resources" : { 
          "DBInstance" : { 
          "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance", 
          "Properties": { 
             "DBInstanceClass" : "db.m2.xlarge", 
             "AllocatedStorage" : "400", 
             "MasterUsername" : "myusername", 
             "MasterUserPassword" : "mypassword", 
             "DBSnapshotIdentifier":"xxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-17-00" 
         } 
      } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Engine is an optional property when DBSnapshotIdentifier is specified. Anyways the above one is not working too! It says "Template contains errors.: Template format error: unsupported type or structure. (line 1, column 1)"

Comment: Are you creating a SQL or Mysql?

Comment: sql server, i tried with both sqlserver-ee and sqlserver-se as well

Comment: Are you sure the Snapshot version is 11? You have to include full version there some thing like this "11.00.2100.60.v1"

Comment: Or remove that engine version fully as you already have the snapshot there. I edited my answer use that.

Comment: Good point , the version needs to be 12.0 for sql server 2014 but that doesn't work either. and i don't think the compiler does compile time validation at that level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117258/discussion-between-error2007s-and-srini).

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note for any one facing this issue if your template has any resource from AWS SAM you must include `Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31` at the beginning of your template.